# Sqlite transaction in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am doing sql transaction in qt.

```
bool X::save()
{
    if (!mDatabase.transaction())
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!saveHeader())
    {
        mDatabase.rollback();
        return false;
    }

    if (!saveBody())
    {
        mDatabase.rollback();
        return false;
    }

    mDatabase.commit();     
    return true;    
}
```

My commit returns fails an returns **"cannot commit - no transaction is active Unable to commit transaction"**

I have SELECT and DELETE query in the functions. But I do **query.clear();** after execution.

Still I get this error. Someone knows why...

Comment: Did `QSqlDatabase::transaction()` return true?

Comment: yes ... i ll update the question

Comment: According to the documentation, "Note: For some databases, the commit will fail and return false if there is an active query using the database for a SELECT. Make the query inactive before doing the commit." (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#commit) Try that.

Comment: @Tarod: I have mentioned in question that I do execute clear() for my SELECT queries.

Comment: Did you try QSqlQuery::finish() before calling your 'save' method? Another attempt would be to delete the QSqlQuery instance to get the same behaviour in order to make the query inactive before calling your 'save' function.